# select max native query hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get the max value of a column in a table using a native query with the `@Query` annotation

I tried to derive it from the examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT max(i.sequence) " +
            "FROM invoices as i " +
            "WHERE i.fleet_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Long findMaxSequence(String fleetId);
```

i ve also tried:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT max(i.sequence) " +
        "FROM invoices as i " +
        "WHERE i.fleet_id = :fleetId", nativeQuery = true)
Long findMaxSequence(@Param("fleetId") String fleetId);
```

When i call my method as :

```
long maxSeq = invoiceRepository.findMaxSequenceForFleetId(invoice.getFleetId());
```

I get a `NullPointerException`. Any ideas why?

`Invoice` entity looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices"}
public class Invoice implements Serializable {


    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    private long sequence;

    @Column(length = 12)
    private String fleetId;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Post the invoices identity

Comment: What do you get as output?

Comment: Well, one strange thing is the difference between 'fleet_id' and 'fleetId' names

Comment: @Acupoftea 
both should be valid, see 5.1 & 6.2 here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the fact that the database was empty so the query was returning `null`

and basic types such as `long` cannot be assigned to null values. Weirdly the compiler did not complain..

I modified my code as below:

```
Long maxSeq = invoiceRepository.findMaxSequenceForFleetId(invoice.getFleetId());
if(maxSeq == null){
    maxSeq = 0L;
}
```